# How to resolve the error "Parsing error: Unexpected token import" in router.js?

Tags: vuejs2

How to resolve unexpected token import eslint error inside router.js?

I have tried this as well.
`'parser': 'babel-eslint'`

My router.js
`const Screen1 = () =>
  import("@/components/run/Screen1");
const Screen2 = () =>
  import(
    "@/components/run/Screen2"
  );`

my package.json
`"eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },`

Answer (score 0):

{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:vue/essential"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },

```
"parserOptions": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module"
},
"plugins": [
    "vue"
],
"rules": {
}
```

}

look at my eslint
important is to close cmd and then run again